# column images full width responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, row, containers, column-width

I'm trying make 2 images take up full width of 2 columns. I want the images to be responsive. This seems like it should be simple but im having problems. I'm getting confused on applying width to container, row, or using table. I would like it to look like the first 2 entry boxes under the carousel on this site minus the animation rollover. http://www.montere.it/?lang=en

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="trans"> <img src="headertrans.jpg">
h3>The Latest</h3>
<p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
<p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a></p>
</div>     
</div>  
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="trans"> <img src="headertrans2.jpg">
<h3>Designs</h3>
<p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
<p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

my css:

.container{width: 100%;
}

.trans{
    transition:.all 0.9s ease;

}

.trans:hover {
    opacity: 0.1;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/tubLg4ge/)**

Since it seems you're using Bootstrap, you'll want to do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center box left">
            <h3>The Latest</h3>
            <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
            <p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center box right">
            <h3>Designs</h3>
            <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{min-height:200px;}
.left{background:url("http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg"); background-size:cover}
.right{background:url("http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg"); background-size:cover}
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, it works but the image is only showing half vertically. The width is awesome working great. I was having probs with this before, and when i put the image in the html instead of the css as bg pic it shows full image. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Glad it helped. Well, depends on the image too, but you could keep it centered with CSS like this. http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/tubLg4ge/5/

Comment: thank man that did it, hope one day to understand code the way i do design, appreciate it

Comment: Sweet! Good luck with the project.

Comment: So i been playing around with the code you gave me. I cant get the <h3> or <p> to be on top of the box transition effect. It blacks out on the hover. How can I have the text on top of the box?